# Get a 'history' of items from JSON column of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has the following format (simplified):

`userid` is a string, `purchased_items` is a JSON string (in the format of a list of dictionaries).

| userid | purchased_items |
| --- | --- |
| U123 | [{"itemid":"I456","t":1649722121709}, {"itemid":"I789","t":1649722118064}, {itemid:"I123", "t": 1649722034610}] |
| U456 | [{"itemid":"I123","t":1649721903646}] |

where itemid is what the user purchased, 't' is the timestamp at which it occurred (the dictionaries are sorted according to descending order of timestamp, so the earliest timestamps are first.).

What I want:
For each user and timestamp, get a list of all the items that was purchased BEFORE and DURING the current timestamp

| userid | timestamp | previously purchased items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| U123 | 1649722121709 | I456 |
| U123 | 1649722118064 | I456 I789 |
| U123 | 1649722034610 | I456 I789 I123 |
| U456 | 1649721903646 | I123 |

**Edit-What I've Tried**
So I've tried to broken down the problem by row first, and plan to create a function from the code below and apply it to each row.

```
visits = df[df['userid']=='U123']['purchased_items'].values[0] #visits is of type list
dict_of_rows = {}
history = []
for i in visits:
  if i is not None:
    obj = json.loads(i)
    dict_of_rows['timestamp'] = obj['t']
    dict_of_rows['history'] = history
    history.append(obj['itemid'])
```

What I get:

```
dict_of_rows
{'history': ['I456', 'I789', 'I123'],
 'timestamp': 1649722034610}
```

This gives me only one row of what I want (row3 of the output table), I want to be able to get the first 3 rows of output table.

And my plan is to use this dictionary of rows to build another dataframe that gives the output table.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you include a snippet of code from your current attempt as well as it's output? It is often easier, faster and a better learning experience to start from your code than from 0.

Comment: @scr I've updated with code I've tried and what I plan to do with it, though I don't think its the best possible way to approach the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert original list of dictionary `purchased_items` column to multiple columns with `explode` and `pd.json_normalize`.

```py
df = df.explode('purchased_items').reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df['userid'], pd.json_normalize(df['purchased_items'])], axis=1).sort_values(['userid', 't'], ascending=[True, False])
```

```
print(df)

  userid itemid              t
0   U123   I456  1649722121709
1   U123   I789  1649722118064
2   U123   I123  1649722034610
3   U456   I123  1649721903646
```

Then you can group by `userid` column then join previous row of current row in each group by `apply` on group rows.

```py
out = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda group: group.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(group.reset_index().loc[:row.name, 'itemid']).strip(), axis=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(out)

0              I456
1         I456 I789
2    I456 I789 I123
3              I123
```

Finally, add the returned Series to original dataframe

```py
df['previously purchased items'] = out
df = df.drop(columns=['itemid']).rename(columns={'t': 'timestamp'})
```

```
print(df_)

  userid      timestamp previously purchased items
0   U123  1649722121709                       I456
1   U123  1649722118064                  I456 I789
2   U123  1649722034610             I456 I789 I123
3   U456  1649721903646                       I123
```

---

If you want to exclude current purchased item, you can change the `groupby` to following

```py
out = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda group: group.assign(temp=group['itemid'].shift(fill_value='')).pipe(lambda g: g.reset_index().apply(lambda row: ' '.join(g.loc[:row.name, 'temp']).strip(), axis=1))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(df)

  userid      timestamp previously purchased items
0   U123  1649722121709
1   U123  1649722118064                       I456
2   U123  1649722034610                  I456 I789
3   U456  1649721903646
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the detailed breakdown of the steps! I added 1 line of code in between line 1 and line 2 of your answer that dealt with null values and json format in my actual data: `df['purchased_items'] = df['purchased_items'].apply(lambda x: '{}' if pd.isna(x) else x).apply(json.loads)` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''userid|purchased_items
U123|[{"itemid":"I456","t":1649722121709}, {"itemid":"I789","t":1649722118064}, {"itemid":"I123", "t": 1649722034610}]
U456|[{"itemid":"I123","t":1649721903646}]'''), delimiter='|')


df['purchased_items'] = df['purchased_items'].apply(lambda x: [list(i.values()) for i in json.loads(x)])
df = df.explode(column='purchased_items')

df['timestamp'] = df['purchased_items'].str[1]
df['previously purchased items'] = df['purchased_items'].str[0]


df['previously purchased items'] = df.groupby('userid')['previously purchased items']\
                .transform(lambda x: pd.concat((x.shift(n) for n in range(x.shape[0])), axis=1, ignore_index=True).values.tolist())

df.drop(columns=['purchased_items'], inplace=True)

df
```

|  | userid | timestamp | previously purchased items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | U123 | 1649722121709 | ['I456', nan, nan] |
| 0 | U123 | 1649722118064 | ['I789', 'I456', nan] |
| 0 | U123 | 1649722034610 | ['I123', 'I789', 'I456'] |
| 1 | U456 | 1649721903646 | ['I123'] |

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I was having issue with using json.loads for my dataframe earlier as well and this error comes up: `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list` when using json.loads() in the first line. The dtype of 'purchased_items' Series is `Object`, and if I go into any individual cell in 'purchased_items' column with `df['purchased_items'].values[0]` the type is `list`

Comment: then skip this like `df['purchased_items'] = df['purchased_items'].apply(lambda x: [list(i.values()) for i in x])`